# Firebreath NPAPI plugin fails after reopening pipes on refresh - cannot reopen pipes successfully (stdin fails) - Mac OS X related

Tags: pipe, exec, fork, stdin, firebreath

I work on custom NPAPI plugin for Mozilla/Safari which has to communicate (exchange messages) with an external native process on Mac.

I use FireBreath framework for plugin development. The external process read from and write to stdin/stdout.

So, FireBreath process (on Mozilla this is *plugin container*) is **parent** process and the external process is **child**. During plugin initialization pipes are created and child process is run using *execv* command - *SetUpPipesAndRunChild* procedure. 
Four separate threads monitor parent's and child's stdin/stdout and process messages.

On first run everything works fine, but if plugin is refreshed *shutdown* procedure will call *TearDownPipes* procedure and immediate after *SetUpPipesAndRunChild* procedure is called again, the parent process keep the same PID, new child process is run (with new PID).

On every refresh parent's stdin fails.

If I turn off the browser and run the plugin from the beginning there is no problem but on refresh fails.

Please take a look at the snippet bellow. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

```
pid_t childPID = -1;
FILE* pWriteFile = NULL;

int writepipe[2] = {-1,-1}, /* parent -> child */
            readpipe [2] = {-1,-1}; /* child -> parent */
int stdinFD_copy, stdoutFD_copy;

void SetUpPipesAndRunChild()
{
     // Read Write pipes
    writepipe[0] = -1;  
    writepipe[1] = -1;  
    readpipe [0] = -1;  
    readpipe [1] = -1;  

    stdinFD_copy = -1;
    stdoutFD_copy = -1;

    stdinFD_copy = dup(fileno(stdin));
    stdoutFD_copy = dup(fileno(stdout));

    if (stdinFD_copy == -1) <log message>
    if (stdoutFD_copy == -1) <log message>

    // Command to execute
    char *Env_argv[] = { (char *)"<path to the native executable>",(char *) 0 };

    if ( pipe(readpipe) < 0) <log message>
    if (pipe(writepipe) < 0 ) <log message>

    childPID = fork();
    if (childPID == 0) // child
    {
        if (close (stdinFD_copy) == -1) <log message>
        if (close(stdoutFD_copy) == -1) <log message>

        if (close(writepipe[1]) == -1) <log message>
        if (close(readpipe[0]) == -1) <log message>

        if (writepipe[0] != fileno(stdin))
        {
            if (dup2(writepipe[0], fileno(stdin)) == -1)  <log message>
            if (close(writepipe[0]) == -1)  <log message>
        }

        if (readpipe[1] != fileno(stdout))
        {
            if (dup2(readpipe[1], fileno(stdout)) == -1) <log message>
            if (close(readpipe[1]) == -1) <log message>
        }

        errno = 0;
        int execReturn = execv(Env_argv[0], Env_argv);
        if(execReturn == -1)  <log message>
        _exit(0); // If exec fails then exit forked process.
    }
    else if (childPID < 0)  <log message> // failed to fork
    else // parent
    {
        if (close(writepipe[0]) == -1) <log message>
        if (close(readpipe[1]) == -1) <log message>

        pWriteFile = fdopen(writepipe[1],"w");
        if (pWriteFile == NULL)  <log message>

        // connect the source end of the readpipe to the parent process fileno(stdin)
        if (readpipe[0] != fileno(stdin))
        {
            if (dup2(readpipe[0], fileno(stdin)) == -1) <log message>
            if (close(readpipe[0]) == -1) <log message>
        }

        stdouThread->setFileWritter(pWriteFile) // this thread write to file, so that pWriteFile is opened on the sink end of the writepipe[1].
        stdouThread->start();
        stdinThread->start(); // stdinThread read std::getline(std::cin, stringVariable)
    }
}

void TearDownPipes
{

    if (childPID > 0)
    {
        stdoutThread->stop();       
        fclose(pWriteFile);
        stdinThread->waitSignal(); //wait here until stdinThread signal it has stopped

        childPID = -1;
        delete pWriteFile;

        if (dup2(stdinFD_copy, fileno(stdin)) == -1)  <log message>
        if (dup2(stdoutFD_copy, fileno(stdout)) == -1)  <log message>
        if (close (stdinFD_copy) == -1)  <log message>
        if (close(stdoutFD_copy) == -1)  <log message>
    }
}
```

Tear down steps are:

```
1. paren's stdoutThread->stop
2. pWriteFile is closed and the file descriptor writepipe[1] is closed
3. child's stdinThread detects broken pipe (cin::fail()) and stop signal is set.
4. childs's stdoutThread->stop
5. parents's stdinThread detects broken pipe (cin::fail()) and stop signal is set.
```

On every SetUpPipesAndRunChild call, file descriptors get the same values

```
stdinFD_copy = 9
stdoutFD_copy = 10
writepipe[0] = 11   
writepipe[1] = 12   
readpipe [0] = 13   
readpipe [1] = 14
```

Comment: Does it need to be a different instance of your external app per instance of the plugin? You could set it up in GlobalInitialize and tear down in GlobalDeinitialize

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the problem, it need to be a different instance.